# Is it possible to change meteor default html extension

Tags: meteor

I am using WebStorm which supports handlebars as long as the file has .handlebars or .hbs extensions.

It looks like all the templates in meteor use the **.html** extension.

Is it possible to customize it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change the extension in the templating smart package.

Open up

```
/packages/templating/package.js
```

and you will see

```js
"html", function (bundle, source_path, serve_path, where) {
```

at or around line 30. Change it to

```js
"hbs", function (bundle, source_path, serve_path, where) {
```

Comment: @OlivierRefalo: They can't go and create settings for every single thing I think, and writing (or fixing) packages is encouraged. If you know `.handlebars` and `.hbs` to be official enough extensions, you could summit a pull request (or at least an issue) on their GitHub where you include these to be handled. If you just do it or yourself copying the package or adjusting the original package should do well. (If you do choose to copy, make sure you run `meteor remove` on the old one and `meteor add` on the new one)

Comment: hum, didn't know I had to run `add` & `remove`. how come `meteor list` doesn't return **templating**  implicit pkg ?

Comment: @OlivierRefalo: Oh wait, yeah. It's indeed implicit so I guess you can't remove it then. Adjusting seems to be the only option. :(

Comment: @OlivierRefalo: Well, another idea is to make an extension called `extensions` which will read out a `.extensions` file (CSV style), and then you simply save each file that gets saved into a folder `extensions` or something like that using an extension that Meteor can handle. For instance, when saving it `file.hbs` it would save `extensions/file.html`. Perhaps `intermediary` is a better name for such folder...

Comment: Hi, I don't have /packages/templating/package.js file, probably after 1.5 years something changed in meteor's internal structure. Could you tell me where can I change it now for the same purpose?

Answer (score -1):

I might be a little late.

I think Webstorm allow you to add extention for handlebars an other plugins.

> To have the plugin handle html files, open Settings->File Types and find "Handlebars" on the list. Then, in the "Registered Patterns" pane below, add "*.html".

Source: github